# Treating mongodb string values as numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

[image]

I'm working with MongoDB and Node.js. I have scraped a bunch of HTML tables and inserted them into preexisting records using

```
await collection.updateOne({ "_id": m._id }, { $set: m.myObj });
```

Unfortunately, these are in string format. I'd like to do some mongo filtering by treating them as numbers. Is there a way to do this?

as an example lets say I wanted to apply the filter:

```
 {'TOTAL DUE': {$gt: 0}}
```

I wouldn't be able to apply this directly, is there a way around this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you just want to go over every record and convert values to numbers?

Comment: I'm pretty new to mongo, so at a high level I'd like know how best to approach this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      INTEREST: {
        $toDouble: "$INTEREST"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Which will convert from:

```
{
    "INTEREST": "1.01"
}
```

To:

```
{
    "INTEREST": 1.01
}
```

Here is an example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/20VAzMWt-oG

For your provided example. I see that you have a double with a currency "$" sign at the beginning.

Here is a solution for that case:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      INTEREST: {
        $convert: {
          input: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: [ { $substr: [ "$INTEREST", 0,1 ] }, { $literal: "$" } ] },
              then: { $substr: [ "$INTEREST", 1, -1 ] },
              else: "$INTEREST"
            }
          },
          to: "double",
          onError: 0.00,
          onNull: 0.00
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

And playground example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/rftjPen4Mtc